# My hosting doesn't let me use ">" and "&" on my Cron job

Tags: laravel, cron

I bought a script to make some tests, and this is the cron job inside the app documentation.

There is any alternative?

this is my cron:

```
php /path/to/website/folder/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Why not just write a wrapper script that uses `>` and `&` and put the wrapper script in the `cron` job?

Comment: Are you getting an error? And out of curiosity, why are you using `>> /dev/null` rather than just `> /dev/null`?

Comment: I bought a script to make some tests, and this is the cron job inside the app documentation.

Comment: I don't understand your last comment. Just make the wrapper script like David Schwartz suggested, wherein you can jump through hoops and cut corners as you like, and call that script plain as it is -- without any redirection.